# Discord %sticky command

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I'm currently trying to create a Discord bot that sends a message when a user with a specified role sends  the command `%sticky This is a test`

I want it to always be the first message in the channel and every time another user types in the channel the bot deletes its last message and posts again. I haven't had any luck online yet even finding a bot that already does this functionality, or where to even start. Here's what I kind of have so far

```js
var lastStickyMessage;

client.on('message', message => {
    if (lastStickyMessage != null) {
       message.channel.fetchMessage(lastStickyMessage)
            .then(retrievedMessage => retrievedMessage.delete());
    }
   message.reply("This is a Sticky Message").then(sent => {
        let lastStickyMessage = sent.id;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors with your variable management: One one hand you create a **new** let with the same name. Since a let is a scoped variable, the `lastStickyMessage` will have a different value inside the sent callback than it has outside of it, since those are two different variables (read more on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)).

Apart from that you should save the last sent ID in a file or somewhere since the var will be reset once you restart your bot (the built in `fs` module could help you with that, you can find the documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)).

One last thing: If you initialize a variable without a value it is not `null` but `undefined`. If you only check using `==` it will still evaluate to `true` (means `null == undefined`) but if you compare using `===`, it will evaluate to false (`null !== undefined`). In your case this is not really a problem but this might be good to know for other cases.